# how to find out the NA values that are longer than 30 mins and replace those NA values by matching with other columns with same prefix

Tags: r

I have a data frame `test`, now I want to find out the NA values in the `SWC_plotand subplot number` and `Tsoil_plot and subplot number` columns that are over 30 mins and replace them with relative matching_columns (same matching numbers to the SWC data) at the same `Time`. If the NA values are less than 30 mins, then leave them as NA, otherwise replace them with the matched column. If both matched columns are NA then using the mean values of the same plot to replace all those NA values (e.g. if "Tsoil_11", "Tsoil_14" are all NA and over 30 mins then use the mean of "Tsoil_13", "Tsoil_12" to replace them, same with Plot 21, 22,23,24.. ).

Here is my test code, but the problem is `rle` function works for vector only not data fame...It's tricky to further on...

```
col_vector <- as.vector(test[,"SWC_11"])
nas <- is.na(col_vector)
consecutive_nas <-rle(as.vector(nas))
consecutive_nas_lengths <- consecutive_nas$lengths
consecutive_nas_values <- consecutive_nas$values
start_idx <- which(consecutive_nas_values== 'TRUE' & consecutive_nas_lengths >= 288)
```

The dataset `test` looks like this:

[image]

```
test<- structure(list(Time = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 25L, 30L, 35L, 40L, 
45L, 50L, 55L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 25L, 30L, 35L, 40L, 45L, 
50L, 55L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 25L), hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), mday = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), mon = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), year = c(120L, 
120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 
120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 
120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L), wday = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), yday = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), isdst = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Tsoil_11 = c(4.82, 4.82, 4.8, 4.82, 
4.82, 4.82, 4.82, 4.82, 4.82, 4.82, 4.78, 4.78, 4.78, 4.78, 4.8, 
4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.78, 4.8, 4.78, 4.76, 4.78, 4.76, 4.76, 4.78, 
4.78, 4.74, 4.76, 4.74), Tsoil_12 = c(3.45, 3.43, 3.45, 3.43, 
3.45, 3.41, 3.43, 3.43, 3.41, 3.41, 3.39, 3.39, 3.39, 3.41, 3.39, 
3.39, 3.39, 3.39, 3.36, 3.36, 3.34, 3.34, 3.36, 3.36, 3.36, 3.34, 
3.32, 3.32, 3.32, 3.34), Tsoil_13 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4.58, NA, NA), Tsoil_14 = c(4.89, 4.89, 4.89, 
4.89, 4.87, 4.91, 4.84, 4.87, 4.87, 4.87, 4.82, 4.87, 4.84, 4.84, 
4.82, 4.84, 4.8, 4.8, 4.82, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.82, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 
4.8, 4.8, 4.76, 4.78), Tsoil_21 = c(5.36, 5.36, 5.36, 5.36, 5.34, 
5.34, 5.36, 5.34, 5.32, 5.34, 5.36, 5.32, 5.32, 5.38, 5.34, 5.32, 
5.34, 5.34, 5.32, 5.34, 5.34, 5.27, 5.27, 5.32, 5.32, 5.3, 5.3, 
5.3, 5.3, 5.3), Tsoil_22 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5.5, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
5.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Tsoil_23 = c(5.17, 5.19, 5.17, 5.17, 
5.17, 5.15, 5.19, 5.17, 5.17, 5.17, 5.15, 5.17, 5.19, 5.15, 5.15, 
5.12, 5.12, 5.15, 5.15, 5.15, 5.12, 5.17, 5.15, 5.1, 5.12, 5.1, 
5.12, 5.12, 5.12, 5.12), Tsoil_24 = c(4.91, 4.91, 4.93, 4.91, 
4.89, 4.89, 4.87, 4.91, 4.89, 4.91, 4.89, 4.89, 4.87, 4.84, 4.89, 
4.87, 4.87, 4.89, 4.82, 4.89, 4.87, 4.84, 4.89, 4.87, 4.87, 4.87, 
4.84, 4.87, 4.87, 4.87), Tsoil_31 = c(5.02, 5.02, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 4.97, 4.97, 4.97, 4.97, 4.97, 4.97, 4.95, 4.95, 4.95, 
4.95, 4.95, 4.95, 4.95, 4.95, 4.92, 4.92, 4.92, 4.92, 4.92, 4.92, 
4.92), Tsoil_32 = c(4.84, 4.84, 4.84, 4.82, 4.84, 4.82, 4.82, 
4.82, 4.82, 4.82, 4.82, 4.79, 4.79, 4.79, 4.79, 4.79, 4.79, 4.79, 
4.79, 4.79, 4.79, 4.77, 4.77, 4.77, 4.77, 4.77, 4.77, 4.77, 4.77, 
4.77), Tsoil_33 = c(4.95, 4.95, 4.95, 4.95, 4.95, 4.95, 4.95, 
4.95, 4.95, 4.95, 4.95, 4.92, 4.95, 4.92, 4.92, 4.92, 4.92, 4.92, 
4.92, 4.9, 4.9, 4.9, 4.9, 4.9, 4.9, 4.9, 4.9, 4.9, 4.9, 4.9), 
    Tsoil_34 = c(4.53, 4.53, 4.53, 4.53, 4.53, 4.53, 4.53, 4.53, 
    4.53, 4.51, 4.51, 4.51, 4.51, 4.51, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 
    4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.45, 4.48, 4.45, 4.45, 4.45, 
    4.45, 4.45), SWC_11 = c(0.1143, 0.1143, 0.1143, 0.1143, 0.1143, 
    0.1143, 0.1136, 0.1143, 0.1143, 0.1136, 0.1143, 0.1136, 0.1143, 
    0.1136, 0.1143, 0.1136, 0.1143, 0.1136, 0.1136, 0.1136, 0.1136, 
    0.1136, 0.1136, 0.1136, 0.1136, 0.1136, 0.1129, 0.1136, 0.1136, 
    0.1136), SWC_12 = c(0.1557, 0.1564, 0.1564, 0.1557, 0.1557, 
    0.1557, 0.1564, 0.1557, 0.1557, 0.1557, 0.1557, 0.1564, 0.1557, 
    0.1557, 0.1557, 0.1557, 0.155, 0.1557, 0.155, 0.155, 0.155, 
    0.1557, 0.155, 0.155, 0.1557, 0.155, 0.155, 0.155, 0.155, 
    0.1543), SWC_13 = c(0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 
    0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 
    0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 
    0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 
    0.1804), SWC_14 = c(0.2044, 0.2044, 0.2044, 0.2044, 0.2044, 
    0.2044, 0.2044, 0.2044, 0.2044, 0.2044, 0.2044, 0.2044, 0.2044, 
    0.2037, 0.2037, 0.2037, 0.2044, 0.2037, 0.2044, 0.2037, 0.2037, 
    0.2037, 0.2044, 0.2037, 0.2037, 0.2037, 0.2037, 0.2037, 0.2037, 
    0.2037), SWC_21 = c(0.2243, 0.2243, 0.2246, 0.2239, 0.2243, 
    0.225, 0.2239, 0.2243, 0.2243, 0.2239, 0.2246, 0.2243, 0.2239, 
    0.2243, 0.2246, 0.2243, 0.2243, 0.2239, 0.2239, 0.2246, 0.2239, 
    0.2243, 0.2239, 0.2239, 0.2243, 0.2239, 0.2239, 0.2235, 0.2243, 
    0.2243), SWC_22 = c(0.2277, 0.2273, 0.2273, 0.2277, 0.2277, 
    0.2273, 0.2269, 0.2273, 0.2277, 0.2273, 0.2269, 0.2269, 0.2277, 
    0.2277, 0.2269, 0.2269, 0.2269, 0.2269, 0.2269, 0.2273, 0.2273, 
    0.2273, 0.2269, 0.2273, 0.2273, 0.2273, 0.2269, 0.2273, 0.2269, 
    0.2273), SWC_23 = c(0.256, 0.2556, 0.2556, 0.256, 0.256, 
    0.2556, 0.2556, 0.2552, 0.2556, 0.2552, 0.2556, 0.256, 0.2563, 
    0.2556, 0.256, 0.256, 0.2556, 0.256, 0.2556, 0.2556, 0.2556, 
    0.256, 0.2556, 0.2567, 0.2556, 0.256, 0.256, 0.2556, 0.2567, 
    0.2556), SWC_24 = c(0.2307, 0.2311, 0.2311, 0.2307, 0.2318, 
    0.2307, 0.2311, 0.2311, 0.2307, 0.2307, 0.2307, 0.2314, 0.2314, 
    0.2307, 0.2311, 0.2307, 0.2303, 0.2311, 0.2311, 0.2307, 0.2311, 
    0.2307, 0.2311, 0.2307, 0.2303, 0.2311, 0.2307, 0.2311, 0.2307, 
    0.2307), SWC_31 = c(0.1143, 0.1143, 0.1143, 0.1143, 0.1143, 
    0.1143, 0.1136, 0.1143, 0.1143, 0.1136, 0.1143, 0.1136, 0.1143, 
    0.1136, 0.1143, 0.1136, 0.1143, 0.1136, 0.1136, 0.1136, 0.1136, 
    0.1136, 0.1136, 0.1136, 0.1136, 0.1136, 0.1129, 0.1136, 0.1136, 
    0.1136), SWC_32 = c(0.1557, 0.1564, 0.1564, 0.1557, 0.1557, 
    0.1557, 0.1564, 0.1557, 0.1557, 0.1557, 0.1557, 0.1564, 0.1557, 
    0.1557, 0.1557, 0.1557, 0.155, 0.1557, 0.155, 0.155, 0.155, 
    0.1557, 0.155, 0.155, 0.1557, 0.155, 0.155, 0.155, 0.155, 
    0.1543), SWC_33 = c(0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 
    0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 
    0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 
    0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 0.1804, 
    0.1804), SWC_34 = c(0.2044, 0.2044, 0.2044, 0.2044, 0.2044, 
    0.2044, 0.2044, 0.2044, 0.2044, 0.2044, 0.2044, 0.2044, 0.2044, 
    0.2037, 0.2037, 0.2037, 0.2044, 0.2037, 0.2044, 0.2037, 0.2037, 
    0.2037, 0.2044, 0.2037, 0.2037, 0.2037, 0.2037, 0.2037, 0.2037, 
    0.2037), Tsoil_Calluna = c(5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 
    5.08, 5.08, 5.08, 5.08, 5.08, 5.08, 5.08, 5.08, 5.08, 5.08, 
    5.08, 5.05, 5.05, 5.05, 5.05, 5.05, 5.05, 5.05, 5.05, 5.05, 
    5.05, 5.05, 5.05, 5.05), Tsoil_Deschampsia = c(5.18, 5.18, 
    5.18, 5.15, 5.15, 5.15, 5.15, 5.15, 5.15, 5.15, 5.15, 5.15, 
    5.15, 5.15, 5.15, 5.13, 5.13, 5.13, 5.13, 5.13, 5.13, 5.13, 
    5.13, 5.13, 5.13, 5.13, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1), SWC_Calluna = c(0.1768, 
    0.1768, 0.1768, 0.1768, 0.1768, 0.1768, 0.1768, 0.1768, 0.1768, 
    0.1768, 0.1768, 0.1768, 0.1768, 0.1768, 0.1768, 0.1768, 0.1768, 
    0.1768, 0.1768, 0.1768, 0.1768, 0.1768, 0.1768, 0.1768, 0.1768, 
    0.1768, 0.1768, 0.1768, 0.1768, 0.1768), SWC_Deschampsia = c(0.1354, 
    0.1354, 0.1354, 0.1354, 0.1354, 0.1354, 0.1354, 0.1354, 0.1354, 
    0.1354, 0.1354, 0.1354, 0.1354, 0.1354, 0.1354, 0.1354, 0.1354, 
    0.1354, 0.1354, 0.1354, 0.1354, 0.1354, 0.1354, 0.1354, 0.1354, 
    0.1354, 0.1354, 0.1354, 0.1354, 0.1354), Tsoil_41 = c(5.23, 
    5.21, 5.21, 5.21, 5.19, 5.21, 5.19, 5.23, 5.21, 5.17, 5.23, 
    5.19, 5.19, 5.17, 5.17, 5.19, 5.15, 5.17, 5.17, 5.19, 5.17, 
    5.15, 5.19, 5.17, 5.17, 5.15, 5.19, 5.17, 5.17, 5.17), Tsoil_42 = c(4.82, 
    4.87, 4.89, 4.84, 4.89, 4.89, 4.87, 4.84, 4.87, 4.89, 4.84, 
    4.93, 4.93, 4.87, 4.89, 4.87, 4.91, 4.87, 4.89, 4.89, 4.91, 
    4.87, 4.91, 4.89, 4.89, 4.91, 4.91, 4.93, 4.93, 4.91), Tsoil_43 = c(4.42, 
    4.39, 4.42, 4.39, 4.39, 4.37, 4.39, 4.37, 4.35, 4.37, 4.35, 
    4.35, 4.35, 4.35, 4.33, 4.33, 4.33, 4.29, 4.33, 4.33, 4.33, 
    4.29, 4.31, 4.31, 4.31, 4.27, 4.29, 4.27, 4.29, 4.27), Tsoil_44 = c(5.19, 
    5.19, 5.19, 5.19, 5.19, 5.15, 5.21, 5.19, 5.17, 5.19, 5.17, 
    5.19, 5.17, 5.19, 5.15, 5.15, 5.19, 5.15, 5.19, 5.12, 5.17, 
    5.15, 5.15, 5.15, 5.15, 5.15, 5.15, 5.15, 5.17, 5.15), Tsoil_51 = c(4.74, 
    4.74, 4.74, 4.72, 4.76, 4.74, 4.74, 4.69, 4.74, 4.72, 4.74, 
    4.69, 4.72, 4.67, 4.69, 4.69, 4.69, 4.72, 4.74, 4.72, 4.67, 
    4.69, 4.67, 4.69, 4.69, 4.72, 4.69, 4.67, 4.69, 4.67), Tsoil_52 = c(4.57, 
    4.54, 4.57, 4.57, 4.54, 4.57, 4.57, 4.54, 4.54, 4.5, 4.57, 
    4.54, 4.54, 4.52, 4.54, 4.52, 4.52, 4.54, 4.54, 4.52, 4.52, 
    4.52, 4.5, 4.52, 4.54, 4.5, 4.52, 4.48, 4.54, 4.5), Tsoil_53 = c(4.22, 
    4.2, 4.2, 4.2, 4.2, 4.18, 4.2, 4.22, 4.16, 4.16, 4.18, 4.18, 
    4.18, 4.18, 4.16, 4.18, 4.18, 4.18, 4.16, 4.16, 4.14, 4.18, 
    4.14, 4.14, 4.16, 4.12, 4.18, 4.14, 4.16, 4.14), Tsoil_54 = c(4.67, 
    4.72, 4.72, 4.72, 4.72, 4.72, 4.72, 4.72, 4.72, 4.72, 4.74, 
    4.74, 4.76, 4.76, 4.72, 4.74, 4.74, 4.72, 4.72, 4.74, 4.76, 
    4.76, 4.74, 4.76, 4.74, 4.76, 4.74, 4.72, 4.76, 4.74), Tsoil_61 = c(5.19, 
    5.17, 5.17, 5.17, 5.19, 5.19, 5.17, 5.17, 5.15, 5.15, 5.17, 
    5.17, 5.15, 5.17, 5.17, 5.17, 5.17, 5.17, 5.21, 5.15, 5.15, 
    5.19, 5.17, 5.17, 5.19, 5.15, 5.19, 5.17, 5.15, 5.17), Tsoil_62 = c(5, 
    4.97, 5, 5, 4.95, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4.95, 5, 4.97, 4.97, 4.97, 
    4.95, 4.97, 4.95, 4.95, 4.95, 4.93, 4.95, 4.97, 4.97, 4.93, 
    4.97, 4.95, 4.93, 4.95, 4.93, 4.97), Tsoil_63 = c(5.1, 5.06, 
    5.08, 5.08, 5.08, 5.08, 5.08, 5.06, 5.06, 5.08, 5.08, 5.08, 
    5.1, 5.06, 5.04, 5.08, 5.1, 5.04, 5.1, 5.08, 5.06, 5.08, 
    5.1, 5.1, 5.04, 5.06, 5.1, 5.04, 5.08, 5.08), Tsoil_64 = c(5.02, 
    5, 5, 5.02, 5.02, 4.97, 5, 5.02, 4.95, 5, 5, 5, 4.97, 5, 
    4.97, 5, 5, 5, 4.97, 4.95, 5, 5, 4.95, 5.02, 5, 4.97, 5, 
    4.97, 4.95, 4.95), SWC_41 = c(0.1986, 0.199, 0.1982, 0.1982, 
    0.1982, 0.1982, 0.1982, 0.1982, 0.1982, 0.1982, 0.1986, 0.199, 
    0.1982, 0.1977, 0.1982, 0.1977, 0.1986, 0.1982, 0.1977, 0.1986, 
    0.1977, 0.1986, 0.1986, 0.1982, 0.1982, 0.1986, 0.1977, 0.1982, 
    0.1986, 0.1982), SWC_42 = c(0.2452, 0.2452, 0.2445, 0.2445, 
    0.2445, 0.2449, 0.2449, 0.2449, 0.2456, 0.2449, 0.2456, 0.2449, 
    0.2449, 0.2449, 0.2449, 0.2456, 0.2449, 0.2449, 0.2445, 0.2445, 
    0.2449, 0.2449, 0.2445, 0.2449, 0.2456, 0.2452, 0.2449, 0.2449, 
    0.2445, 0.2449), SWC_43 = c(0.2538, 0.253, 0.2541, 0.2526, 
    0.2526, 0.2534, 0.253, 0.2534, 0.2526, 0.253, 0.253, 0.2523, 
    0.2534, 0.253, 0.253, 0.253, 0.2534, 0.2526, 0.253, 0.2526, 
    0.2538, 0.2526, 0.2523, 0.2526, 0.2523, 0.2534, 0.2523, 0.253, 
    0.2526, 0.253), SWC_44 = c(0.2204, 0.2208, 0.2204, 0.2208, 
    0.2208, 0.2208, 0.2208, 0.2212, 0.2204, 0.2208, 0.2204, 0.2208, 
    0.2204, 0.2204, 0.2204, 0.2204, 0.2204, 0.2204, 0.2204, 0.2204, 
    0.2204, 0.22, 0.2254, 0.2196, 0.22, 0.2204, 0.22, 0.2208, 
    0.2204, 0.2208), SWC_51 = c(0.2348, 0.2352, 0.2352, 0.2352, 
    0.2348, 0.2359, 0.2356, 0.2352, 0.2348, 0.2352, 0.2352, 0.2348, 
    0.2356, 0.2348, 0.2348, 0.2352, 0.2352, 0.2356, 0.2352, 0.2348, 
    0.2352, 0.2352, 0.2352, 0.2356, 0.2356, 0.2352, 0.2356, 0.2352, 
    0.2367, 0.2352), SWC_52 = c(0.2694, 0.2701, 0.2694, 0.2697, 
    0.269, 0.2694, 0.2682, 0.2694, 0.2697, 0.2694, 0.2694, 0.2694, 
    0.269, 0.2694, 0.269, 0.2694, 0.2686, 0.269, 0.2694, 0.269, 
    0.2701, 0.2709, 0.2694, 0.2701, 0.2694, 0.269, 0.269, 0.2739, 
    0.2694, 0.2694), SWC_53 = c(0.2449, 0.2449, 0.2449, 0.2445, 
    0.2441, 0.2449, 0.2445, 0.2445, 0.2456, 0.2449, 0.2449, 0.2449, 
    0.2445, 0.2449, 0.2449, 0.2445, 0.2449, 0.2456, 0.2449, 0.2445, 
    0.2449, 0.2441, 0.2449, 0.2441, 0.2449, 0.2449, 0.2449, 0.2449, 
    0.2452, 0.2449), SWC_54 = c(0.2427, 0.2427, 0.2427, 0.2427, 
    0.2419, 0.2423, 0.2427, 0.2427, 0.2427, 0.2427, 0.2427, 0.2427, 
    0.2427, 0.2427, 0.2427, 0.2419, 0.2427, 0.2423, 0.2423, 0.2423, 
    0.2423, 0.2427, 0.2423, 0.2427, 0.2427, 0.2427, 0.2423, 0.2423, 
    0.2427, 0.2427), SWC_61 = c(0.233, 0.2326, 0.2326, 0.233, 
    0.233, 0.233, 0.2333, 0.2337, 0.233, 0.2333, 0.2326, 0.2326, 
    0.2337, 0.233, 0.233, 0.2337, 0.233, 0.233, 0.233, 0.2322, 
    0.233, 0.233, 0.233, 0.2326, 0.233, 0.233, 0.233, 0.2337, 
    0.233, 0.233), SWC_62 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 0.2545, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), SWC_63 = c(0.2545, 0.2545, 0.2538, 0.2545, 
    0.2545, 0.2545, 0.2545, 0.2541, 0.2545, 0.2545, 0.2541, 0.2541, 
    0.2541, 0.2545, 0.2552, 0.2545, 0.2545, 0.2545, 0.2545, 0.2549, 
    0.2545, 0.2552, 0.2545, 0.2545, 0.2545, 0.2541, 0.2541, 0.2545, 
    0.2552, 0.2545), SWC_64 = c(0.2519, 0.2523, 0.253, 0.2515, 
    0.2515, 0.2515, 0.2512, 0.2519, 0.2523, 0.2519, 0.2526, 0.2519, 
    0.2512, 0.2523, 0.2515, 0.2515, 0.2523, 0.2523, 0.2523, 0.2526, 
    0.2515, 0.2515, 0.2523, 0.2526, 0.2515, 0.2515, 0.2515, 0.2523, 
    0.2515, 0.2526), Tsoil_11_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2), Tsoil_12_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2), Tsoil_13_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Tsoil_14_flag = c(2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Tsoil_21_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Tsoil_22_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Tsoil_23_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2), Tsoil_24_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2), Tsoil_31_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
    Tsoil_32_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Tsoil_33_flag = c(2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Tsoil_34_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), SWC_11_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2), SWC_12_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2), SWC_13_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), SWC_14_flag = c(2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), SWC_21_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), SWC_22_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2), SWC_23_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2), SWC_24_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), SWC_31_flag = c(2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), SWC_32_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), SWC_33_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2), SWC_34_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2), Tsoil_Calluna_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2), Tsoil_Deschampsia_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2), SWC_Calluna_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2), SWC_Deschampsia_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2), Tsoil_41_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Tsoil_42_flag = c(2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Tsoil_43_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Tsoil_44_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Tsoil_51_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2), Tsoil_52_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2), Tsoil_53_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
    Tsoil_54_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Tsoil_61_flag = c(2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Tsoil_62_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Tsoil_63_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Tsoil_64_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2), SWC_41_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2), SWC_42_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), SWC_43_flag = c(2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), SWC_44_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), SWC_51_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2), SWC_52_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2), SWC_53_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), SWC_54_flag = c(2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), SWC_61_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), SWC_62_flag = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1), SWC_63_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2), SWC_64_flag = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")
```

and the matching column numbers are:

```
matching_columns <- list(
  c("Tsoil_11", "Tsoil_14"),
  c("Tsoil_13", "Tsoil_12"),
  c("Tsoil_21", "Tsoil_24"),
  c("Tsoil_22", "Tsoil_23"),
  c("Tsoil_33", "Tsoil_34"),
  c("Tsoil_31", "Tsoil_32"),
  c("Tsoil_41", "Tsoil_44"),
  c("Tsoil_42", "Tsoil_43"),
  c("Tsoil_51", "Tsoil_52"),
  c("Tsoil_53", "Tsoil_54"),
  c("Tsoil_61", "Tsoil_64"),
  c("Tsoil_62", "Tsoil_63")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr::consecutive_id()` to group consecutive `NA`s/non-`NA`s and
with `cumsum()` we can then detect each run of `NA`s that is 30 mins or longer.

Here is an example function that “treats” one `var1`, pulling in data from
the matching `var2` when the 30 minute condition is met,
or from `var3` and `var4` whenever the first pair are both `NA`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

replace_NA_with_matching_var <-
  function(var1, var2, var3, var4, output_name) {
    tibble(var1, var2, var3, var4,
           grp_id = consecutive_id(is.na(var1))) |>
      group_by(grp_id) |>
      mutate(max_cumsum = max(cumsum(is.na(var1)))) |>
      rowwise() |>
      mutate(replace = case_when(
        max_cumsum >= 7 & is.na(var1) & is.na(var2) ~ mean(c(var3, var4), na.rm = TRUE),
        max_cumsum >= 7 ~ var2,
        TRUE ~ var1
      )) |>
      ungroup() |>
      select(!!sym(output_name) := replace)
  }
```

We can use this function to “treat” one variable like this:

```r
replace_NA_with_matching_var(test$SWC_62,
                             test$SWC_63,
                             test$SWC_61,
                             test$SWC_64,
                             "SWC_62")
#> # A tibble: 30 × 1
#>    SWC_62
#>     <dbl>
#>  1  0.254
#>  2  0.254
#>  3  0.254
#>  4  0.254
#>  5  0.254
#>  6  0.254
#>  7  0.254
#>  8  0.254
#>  9  0.254
#> 10  0.254
#> # ℹ 20 more rows
```

To automate this for all variables we create a list that contains each
combination of matching variables in the order we need to feed them into
`replace_NA_with_matching_var()`.

```r
# Create SWC matches
swc_matching_columns <-
  map(matching_columns, str_replace_all, "Tsoil", "SWC")

# Combine Tsoil and SWC matches
all_matching_columns <-
  c(matching_columns,
    swc_matching_columns)

# Reverse order for each match
all_matching_columns_bidirectional <-
  c(all_matching_columns,
    map(all_matching_columns, rev))

# Split into groups of 2 matches
matching_columns_split <-
  split(all_matching_columns_bidirectional,
        ceiling(1:length(all_matching_columns_bidirectional) / 2))

# Add reversed matches
all_matching_columns_split <-
  c(matching_columns_split,
    map(matching_columns_split, rev))
```

Finally we iteratively feed the `all_matching_columns_split` into
`replace_NA_with_matching_var()` using
`purrr::map()`.

```r
map(
  all_matching_columns_split,
  \(x) replace_NA_with_matching_var(test[[x[[1]][1]]],
                                    test[[x[[1]][2]]],
                                    test[[x[[2]][1]]],
                                    test[[x[[2]][2]]],
                                    x[[1]][[1]])
) |>
  bind_cols()
#> # A tibble: 30 × 48
#>    Tsoil_11 Tsoil_21 Tsoil_33 Tsoil_41 Tsoil_51 Tsoil_61 SWC_11 SWC_21 SWC_33
#>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1     4.82     5.36     4.95     5.23     4.74     5.19  0.114  0.224  0.180
#>  2     4.82     5.36     4.95     5.21     4.74     5.17  0.114  0.224  0.180
#>  3     4.8      5.36     4.95     5.21     4.74     5.17  0.114  0.225  0.180
#>  4     4.82     5.36     4.95     5.21     4.72     5.17  0.114  0.224  0.180
#>  5     4.82     5.34     4.95     5.19     4.76     5.19  0.114  0.224  0.180
#>  6     4.82     5.34     4.95     5.21     4.74     5.19  0.114  0.225  0.180
#>  7     4.82     5.36     4.95     5.19     4.74     5.17  0.114  0.224  0.180
#>  8     4.82     5.34     4.95     5.23     4.69     5.17  0.114  0.224  0.180
#>  9     4.82     5.32     4.95     5.21     4.74     5.15  0.114  0.224  0.180
#> 10     4.82     5.34     4.95     5.17     4.72     5.15  0.114  0.224  0.180
#> # ℹ 20 more rows
#> # ℹ 39 more variables: SWC_41 <dbl>, SWC_51 <dbl>, SWC_61 <dbl>,
#> #   Tsoil_14 <dbl>, Tsoil_24 <dbl>, Tsoil_34 <dbl>, Tsoil_44 <dbl>,
#> #   Tsoil_52 <dbl>, Tsoil_64 <dbl>, SWC_14 <dbl>, SWC_24 <dbl>, SWC_34 <dbl>,
#> #   SWC_44 <dbl>, SWC_52 <dbl>, SWC_64 <dbl>, Tsoil_13 <dbl>, Tsoil_22 <dbl>,
#> #   Tsoil_31 <dbl>, Tsoil_42 <dbl>, Tsoil_53 <dbl>, Tsoil_62 <dbl>,
#> #   SWC_13 <dbl>, SWC_22 <dbl>, SWC_31 <dbl>, SWC_42 <dbl>, SWC_53 <dbl>, …
```

Comment: Error in consecutive_id(is.na(var1)) : 
could not find function "consecutive_id"

Comment: `consecutive_id()` is a `dplyr` function. Make sure your `dplyr` version is up-to-date and loaded with either `library(dplyr)` or `library(tidyverse)`